# Regex: Identify strings missing spaces

Tags: python, regex

I have a file of names as strings that are missing spaces in various places.

EX:

```
x = "Red Wings Toast Box Pillow"  
y = "BottlePillLastFly"  
z = "DoorCorn JellowHall Minced Meat"  

#Desired Output:

x = ["Red Wings Toast Box Pillow"]  
y = ["Bottle", "Pill", "Last", "Fly"]  
z = ["Door", "Corn", "Jellow", "Hall", "Minced Meat"]
```

I need to identify any strings that are missing spaces. "DoorCorn" = "Door Corn".
My problem is finding a solution that DOES NOT identify instances where Names are formatted correctly.

Any ideas on how to accomplish the desired outputs? Basically, if the string already contains spaces, then it should stay as one string. If the string is missing spaces, then it should be a list of strings.

Comment: I think the pattern here is rather "check if there are words that contain a capital letter that is not the first letter of the word". You seem to be too focused on spaces.

Comment: Are you sure the desired output should be like that? Perhaps you meant x should be split into a list of its words?

Comment: I have the desired output correct. X should be one single string.

Comment: @MikeScotty Any idea how to write a regex that would solve this without wrongly identifying instances where the string is already correct, like in ex. X ?

Comment: Your question currently shows no effort of solving the problem yourself. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) . Keep in mind that SO is no code writing service, but we'll gladly help if you actually get stuck. Not knowing how to start is not really something we can help you with. Personal opinion: regex is overkill for this task, but it's a possibility.

Comment: @MikeScotty I've been working on this problem for 3 hours now. Shall I post my attempts that have not solved the problem? If not for RegEx, what would you suggest to use?

Comment: ``Shall I post my attempts that have not solved the problem?`` - well yes, that helps us to figure out your skill level, your way of thinking and it shows us that you've actually tried something before you've posted here. How else could we know that?

Comment: @MikeScotty Noted. I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this approach:

```py
import re

x = "Red Wings Toast Box Pillow"  
y = "BottlePillLastFly"  
z = "DoorCorn JellowHall Minced Meat"  

def convert_to_words(s):
    if not re.match(r'[A-Z][^A-Z\s]*[A-Z]', s): return [s]
    return list(re.findall(r'[A-Z][^A-Z]+(?=\s|$|[A-Z])', s))

print(convert_to_words(x))
print(convert_to_words(y))
print(convert_to_words(z))
```

## Explanation:

`re.match` returns a match object if the regex matches the string, and `None` otherwise. So we first check if the string is already formatted correctly, and if so, we return the original string.

If not, we return all occurrences of the string which have a capital letter at the start (`[A-Z]`), followed by multiple non capital letters (`[^A-Z]+`), which are followed by either a space, a capital letter, or the ending of the string (`(?=\s|$|[A-Z])`).

If you don't know what `(?=)` stands for, it is a positive lookahead, a very powerful tool in regex [which you can learn more about here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-regex-lookahead/).